# What kind of database I should use and how to design a database for ad network platform

Tags: mongodb, redis, couchbase

I want to build a ad serving platform like serving ads by words in the content. I want to make word as affiliated link. I have some campaigns with some tags words. When request comes to ad serving API it should serve suitable campaign for those words with some additional conditions. like device type and location etc... I've tried with Redis, couchbase and mongo but My API is not serving within a sec. please suggest me some database and how to design database.

Comment: Redis can be very fast, as it maintains the dataset in memory, not secondary storage. Have you tried benchmarking the different parts of your application to identify the performance bottleneck?

Comment: Yes I've tried with Redis but I want to apply some conditions while querying. where queries won't work in redis right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably not the database you are using but how the datais structured and indexed. Mongodb and Redis can both be as fast as it gets, as well as more traditional relational dbs for this problem.
If using mongo for example and you have a campaign documents with a field containing an array of tag words, you should index that field, and results can be very fast.

Comment: Hi Oren geva, Yes tried the same but the thing is looping. there are more loops for input words. so here one request taking more than a sec to process on one lack campaigns. I'll try again. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Perhaps you need some index/search system, not a db. solr, elastic search etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take some keywords and find an ad campaign that fits those keywords.

Eg. "car" and "texas" keywords might be used to find an ad campaign for car dealerships in Texas. Basically, you add the tags and find the best fit. Is this correct?

Couchbase has full text search capabilities. This is probably the most efficient way to query the database for word matching if you want to match multiple input words with a list of words stored with your campaign document.